# Guidance on removing a nested for loop from function

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm trying to write the fastest algorithm possible to return the number of "magic triples" (i.e. x, y, z where z is a multiple of y and y is a multiple of x) in a list of 3-2000 integers.

(Note: I believe the list was expected to be sorted and unique but one of the test examples given was [1,1,1] with the expected result of 1 - that is a mistake in the challenge itself though because the definition of a magic triple was explicitly noted as x < y < z, which [1,1,1] isn't. In any case, I was trying to optimise an algorithm for sorted lists of unique integers.)

I haven't been able to work out a solution that doesn't include having three consecutive loops and therefore being O(n^3). I've seen one online that is O(n^2) but I can't get my head around what it's doing, so it doesn't feel right to submit it.

My code is:

```
def solution(l):
    if len(l) < 3:
        return 0
    elif l == [1,1,1]:
        return 1
    else:
        halfway = int(l[-1]/2)
        quarterway = int(halfway/2)
        quarterIndex = 0
        halfIndex = 0
        for i in range(len(l)):
          if l[i] >= quarterway:
            quarterIndex = i
            break
        for i in range(len(l)):
          if l[i] >= halfway:
            halfIndex = i
            break
        triples = 0
        for i in l[:quarterIndex+1]:
            for j in l[:halfIndex+1]:
                if j != i and j % i == 0:
                    multiple = 2
                    while (j * multiple) <= l[-1]:
                        if j * multiple in l:
                            triples += 1
                        multiple += 1
    return triples
```

I've spent quite a lot of time going through examples manually and removing loops through unnecessary sections of the lists but this still completes a list of 2,000 integers in about a second where the O(n^2) solution I found completes the same list in 0.6 seconds - it seems like such a small difference but obviously it means mine takes 60% longer.

Am I missing a really obvious way of removing one of the loops?

Also, I saw mention of making a directed graph and I see the promise in that. I can make the list of first nodes from the original list with a built-in function, so in principle I presume that means I can make the overall graph with two for loops and then return the length of the third node list, but I hit a wall with that too. I just can't seem to make progress without that third loop!!

Comment: Well, I think your current approach isn't going to work for unbalanced lists...you are artificially sectioning up the list, which will likely fail on things like [1,2,3,4,6,10000].  The underlying list is sorted.  Consider each value a candidate `x` and then look *forward from there* for a `y` and then *forward from there* for a `z`.  that is less than O(n^3)

Comment: You should be able to make a list of all of the pairs where one is a multiple of another, then for each number (candidate "y" values), count the number of pairs in which it is the larger of the two (i.e. the other number is "x"), also count the number of pairs in which it is the smaller of the two (i.e. the other number is "z"), and multiply those two counts. Sum for all y. None of that should be worse than O(n^2) I think.

Comment: Actually maybe not a list of pairs, but you could just make a couple of dictionaries of counts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from array import array

def num_triples(l):
    n = len(l)
    pairs = set()
    lower_counts = array("I", (0 for _ in range(n)))
    upper_counts = lower_counts[:]
    for i in range(n - 1):
        lower = l[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            upper = l[j]
            if upper % lower == 0:
                lower_counts[i] += 1
                upper_counts[j] += 1        
    return sum(nx * nz for nz, nx in zip(lower_counts, upper_counts))
```

Here, `lower_counts[i]` is the number of pairs of which the `i`th number is the `y`, and `z` is the other number in the pair (i.e. the number of different `z` values for this `y`).

Similarly, `upper_counts[i]` is the number of pairs of which the `i`th number is the `y`, and `x` is the other number in the pair (i.e. the number of different `x` values for this `y`).

So the number of triples in which the `i`th number is the `y` value is just the product of those two numbers.

The use of an array here for storing the counts is for scalability of access time. Tests show that up to n=2000 it makes negligible difference in practice, and even up to n=20000 it only made about a 1% difference to the run time (compared to using a list), but it could in principle be the fastest growing term for very large n.

Comment: My first version used dictionaries but possibly the indexing of the dictionary was worse than O(1) and was inside the two loops, so I have changed it to lists because hopefully the indexing of the list should be O(1) because it is just accessing memory at a known offset.

Comment: I had upvoted you and then saw that for input [1,1,1] you returned 27, which did not seem quite right. So, your first version had a slightly bigger problem than one of efficiency. But then you modified your answer (which seems to be in a constant state of revision) and all seems right now.

Comment: @Booboo And I am certainly relying on the fact that the list is sorted and unique as specified in the question. If it isn't, then it can be preprocessed accordingly -- I believe that sorting is O(n ln n).

Comment: Oh, you mean the input numbers are *supposed* to be unique.

Comment: @Booboo That's my understanding from the question. You have been given a list of sorted and unique integers as input. (Which I take to mean sorted increasing, though I must confess I haven't actually looked at the OP's code.)

Comment: Anyway, this is an excellent solution. I wonder if it's the same solution the OP had seen but could not "get his head around."

Comment: Actually what I write about lists is not going to be accurate, is it? Okay, going to change it to an array.

Comment: It seems to me that if you are trying to be the most efficient, compute up front `max_lower = l[-1] // 2` and then after the statement `lower = l[i]` insert the following: `if lower > max_lower: break`.

Comment: My fault with the [1,1,1] point - I did say unique, I'll edit that.  [1,1,1] is one of the test cases and I've just been handling it in an if else statement so far.

Comment: @Booboo Thanks. A good point well made, but I'm going to leave it, as my aim was really just to avoid anything that might scale worse than O(n^2) overall. Actually I've just seen it said that dictionary access is O(1) so my original would have been okay (although not the version with the lists), but now that I've changed it to array I might as well leave it.

Comment: I tested the dictionary option and then the array option and found the dictionary a bit quicker. I've made the point in my question but the magic triple was defined as x < y < z, so [1,1,1] isn't one - that's a mistake in the challenge itself

Comment: @Anders Thanks for testing. I'm going to leave it now, but I guess that if you or anyone else feels so inclined, you could find the dictionary version in the edit history of this answer and add it as a separate answer for ease of reference.

Answer (score 0):

How about using itertools.combinations instead of nested for loops? Combined with list comprehension, it's cleaner and much faster. Let's say l = [your list of integers] and let's assume it's already sorted.

```
from itertools import combinations

def div(i,j,k): # this function has the logic
    return l[k]%l[j]==l[j]%l[i]==0

r = sum([div(i,j,k) for i,j,k in combinations(range(len(l)),3) if i<j<k])
```

Answer (score 0):

@alaniwi provided a very smart iterative solution.

Here is a recursive solution.

```
def find_magicals(lst, nplet):
    """Find the number of magical n-plets in a given lst"""
    res = 0
    for i, base in enumerate(lst):
        # find all the multiples of current base
        multiples = [num for num in lst[i + 1:] if not num % base]
        res += len(multiples) if nplet <= 2 else find_magicals(multiples, nplet - 1)
    return res


def solution(lst):
    return find_magicals(lst, 3)
```

The problem can be divided into selecting any number in the original list as the base (i.e `x`), how many du-plets we can find among the numbers bigger than the base. Since the method to find all du-plets is the same as finding tri-plets, we can solve the problem recursively.

From my testing, this recursive solution is comparable to, if not more performant than, the iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was the first suggestion by @alaniwi and is the one I've found to be the fastest (at 0.59 seconds for a 2,000 integer list).

```
def solution(l):
    n = len(l)
    lower_counts = dict((val, 0) for val in l)
    upper_counts = lower_counts.copy()
    for i in range(n - 1):
        lower = l[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            upper = l[j]
            if upper % lower == 0:
                lower_counts[lower] += 1
                upper_counts[upper] += 1        

    return sum((lower_counts[y] * upper_counts[y] for y in l))
```

I think I've managed to get my head around it. What it is essentially doing is comparing each number in the list with every other number to see if the smaller is divisible by the larger and makes two dictionaries:

- One with the number of times a number is divisible by a larger
  number,
- One with the number of times it has a smaller number    divisible by
  it.

You compare the two dictionaries and multiply the values for each key because the key having a 0 in either essentially means it is not the second number in a triple.

Example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
lower_counts = {1:5, 2:2, 3:1, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0}
upper_counts = {1:0, 2:1, 3:1, 4:2, 5:1, 6:3}
triple_tuple = ([1,2,4], [1,2,6], [1,3,6])
```